# Do my C++ apps depend on the .Net framework?

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2012

I'm using Visual Studio as my IDE. Will my C++ applications depend on .Net, the way C#, VB.NET and ASP.NET do?

Comment: Depends whether you mean C++ or C++/CLI.

Comment: It'll require the Visual C++ Runtime usually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, only the Visual Studio IDE depends on .NET, not your C++ programs written in it.

(Unless you use .NET libraries of course.)

Comment: I not using .NET libraries,so it's mean my C++ are not depend on .NET, when i compiled and built the application. TQ for the quick feedback. Whoah, stackoverflow is very good for beginner like my to ask. Thank you very much.